# TypeScript: Type inference + Generic Type + "prop" in condition throws an error

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I encountered following problem (abstracted) in a project and I'm really confused if I'm doing something wrong:

```
const fooState = {
  normal: {
    normalProp: "string",
  },
  normal2: {
    normalProp: 0,
  },
  weird: {
    weirdProp: "anything",
  },
};

type fooKeys = keyof typeof fooState;

export const getFooState = <T1 extends fooKeys>(arg: T1) => {
  const foundState = fooState[arg];
  if ("weirdProp" in foundState) {
    console.log(foundState.weirdProp); // This line throws an error, even though it is a practical possibility.
  }

  return foundState;
};
```

The code should suffice to explain my problem. My goal is to handle a specific case differently when the `foundState` object has a specific property.

In my example, if the argument `arg` is passed as `"weird"`, the console log will / should fire but TS throws an error. Why is that?

I appreciate all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like typescript needs an explicit type guard for your case. A dynamic way to define a simple single level type guard function is

```
function dynamicCheckTopLevel<V>(a:any,b:V): a is V {
    let keys = Object.keys(b)
    return keys.every(k => k in a)
}
```

You could also use a type guard specifically for that prop, then you can be explicit about the type rather than deriving from a passed in object that has a sample value for the key

```
function weirdCheck(x:any): x is {weirdProp:any}{
  return x.weirdProp;
}
```

then the error goes away

```
export const getFooState = <T1 extends fooKeys>(arg: T1) => {
  const foundState = fooState[arg];
  if (dynamicCheckTopLevel(foundState, {weirdProp:5})) { //had to give weirdProp a value, for your purpose it can be anything
    console.log(foundState.weirdProp); 
  }

  return foundState;
};
```

If you want to go for a deeper dynamic type guard you can use

```
function dynamicDeepCheck<V>(a:any,b:V): a is V {
    let keys = Object.keys(b) as Array<keyof V>
    return keys.every(key => {
      if(typeof b[key] === "object"){ 
        return dynamicDeepCheck(a[key], b[key])
      }
      return (a[key] && typeof a[key] === typeof b[key])
    })
}
```

In the top level type guard I omitted the value typeof matching check since your implicit type guard condition didn't seem to care about the value of the prop.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEBlKBDKBTGBeGBvAKBhjBACcBbVAGwC58jiTyrqAFMkAB3oCJoyASzABzXgBpGAX0nFSlGgCZ6hJswXtOPGAAZZMGYwDuGQWQAmKxsRNnzHbn1RgAnlAAWwsfsNSA3AQEUC5cWAggANIYLhA4MADW0SBwMMGhyfCIKOgYAQRwAK5gwFCC4DDmLmCoFILAAMLuGMDxACrcADIYAG4Y1AA8AGoAfAAUqLTOLuIARrSDAJT0qDCCsYMMatQYsIkxcQDyMwBWzVAAdHsQozML1jBkOwVkYAnREOc9GGQuo-E4wwSq1eqDuUkChWKpXKlWqtWAABEMBguI1mvEhmMJlNZvMljAVmsYBtVExtrt3ocTmdLu8bgsCbEAIJkMioFz9PYZEb3R5QZ6vK6fXo-P7RAGbNSrOCjNIYDIzADaewAujhsLheCBqSVeAs8DB7mo+QKKlUanUkSi0S1xsroirxDAlaq7lKDEaHk8XjA7aqYAAyAOpELylKoe0uNUa3ByhWRlVuphSMGBUCQWAiHYAMSyaEwcX6rQAjDAMAAPTBgcyxcJRGJYsgieglhnYQGk9PQTJFczZAu4cL9jCK1BNlUBYiMQQpUawi2I5Gopq2hC94dOvC2CwOHi8ACsvBTDINAHpT0ZBNRqDAuKgIBBGF2QNtztQQCJRsWk8Rn6-35+a7VsO5zbvYWgLH4hrEOCxAzr687wlay7oqMQF9vmGCbmBu60Pux74DA56XtezCwHeD73H+GBvh+oyKD+MDUbRgEgOumGgaYO4QVB0jTrOiGWkuNrxGhbHAZh2FceBjj7k6UC0HgUAAPoQAUczFlIBFnheV43nAqBXlR4AQC+NEAaMADMjHMRZ6EgThPHQR6cECea8Iie0XBdL01BiexORSXYuH4QsJ5EbppEUY+ai2XRAAsNkmWZLH+RJOSccFTl8cQJo+vZmEBP4gRZlAubIJhoy8GBepAA)